# Could we add on the 'about' page that questions should be edited to provide more information?

Tags: feature-request, comments, editing, asking-questions

On both the [about page](https://askubuntu.com/about) it is explained how the site works. To my eyes, this should include that a user asking question should *edit* his post to improve it if some other users are asking clarification or to provide more information.

Even in the [help area on asking](https://askubuntu.com/help/asking), there's nothing about that either! This results in loads of new users trying to post comments to include more information.

So, could we either (or preferably both):

- Include a topic on the help page on asking, e.g.:

  > #### Someone asks for more information in a comment. Should I reply or edit my question?
  >
  > On a Q&A site it's a convention that you include all information in the question body rather than posting information in comments. It is also not needed to put a new section "update" in your question body, as we can see that you've edited your question. Your question will also appear on top of the "Active" list again.
- Include a short section on improving a question or how to handle comments.